# How do I test yield_control multiple times to a block that raises an error?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'd like to use the `yield_control` matcher in RSpec like so

```
expect {|b| some_method(&b) }.to yield_control.exactly(5).times
```

However, I'd like the block to *raise an error*. Is there an RSpec construct that allows you to do this?

Basically, I'm looking for something like an RSpec mock object that allows you to raise an error whenever the block is yielded to and count the number of times it was yielded to.

I understand there are other ways of doing it by defining my own block that keeps track of how many times it has been called, but I was hoping there is a built-in that does something like this.

**Example:**

```
def some_method(&block)
  attempt = 0
  begin
    attempt += 1
    yield
  rescue => e
    retry if attempt < 3
  end
end
```

I'd like to test that control is yielded a certain number of times when the block raises an error. I understand that this is one way to do it:

```
number_of_times = 0
some_method do
  number_of_times += 1
  raise StandardError
end
expect(number_of_times).to eq(3)
```

But I was hoping I could use the `expect {..}.to yield_control` syntax.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question here? Can you provide an example of the intended behavior?

Comment: So you want to test 2 conditions at once? You want to test that it yielded control 3 times and then raised an error? Like @diego.greyrobot stated I don't think there is a way to do this with a single construct in any efficient manner.

Answer (score -1):

Are you expecting the block to raise an error? There is an Rspec matcher for that: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: Yes but that doesn't test that control was yielded multiple times.

Comment: Right, you still have to wrap that expectation in your other expectation that will then yield control. There is no single construct that will do both at the same time.

Comment: Right. Interesting test case, I guess. Since the only way I can test that it actually yields control multiple times is by having the block raise an error.

Comment: @DiegoSalazar please could you update the answer as per your comment?